# GoogleApiClient not connected yet

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-api

`googleApiClient.connect();` method does not work.

And, `googleApiClient.isConnected()` is returns always false

I have followed the instructions given below:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: likely you are using it incorrectly. Show where you call those methods.

Comment: Inside the logout funtion

googleApiClient.connect();
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
 new ResultCallback<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status>() {
           @Override
           public void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status) {
            updateUI(false);
           }
        });

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: you have to wait until the client connects actually before doing something with it. It connects asynchronously